# How do you append <p> tags to a foreign object in D3.JS

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, append

In D3, I've made a group element with a circle and text. But I'd like the text to be in html so that I can add inline style. I understand that you need to append a foreignObject to use html text ...so I've made this:

```
var focusCPIfore = canvasCPI.append("g")

focusCPIfore.append("circle").attr("r", 5);
focusCPIfore.append("foreignObject").append("xhtml:body").attr("class", "sansserifbold");
```

Then I have a this inside a function so when its called I will (hopefully) add text to the body tag I just appended. So far this works with no errors:

```
        focusCPIfore.select("foreignObject")
        .transition()
        .delay(300)
        .select("xhtml:body");
```

..but how do I add html text to that body tag once its selected?  I've tried this but it doesnt work:

```
        focusCPIfore.select("foreignObject")
        .transition()
        .delay(300)
        .select("xhtml:body").html(<p></p>);
```

Comment: You need quotes around the content: `.html("<p></p>")`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Lars Kotthoff, you need quotes around the content:

```
.select("xhtml:body").html("<p></p>");
```

However I am not sure that in a foreignObject context, it would be enough, I think that you should also add the `xhtml` namespace, as you did for `xhtml:body`. This would give:

```
.select("xhtml:body").html("<xhtml:p></xhtml:p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

While you do need quotes around the HTML string that you're inserting via the .html method, it doesn't look like you need to re-specify the name space again.

Mike's actually got a very simple example at:

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1424037